# Horror/thriller movie about a man locked in because he had in his gene/blood the proximity to sexual depravity

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

Could anyone name the movie that used to be shown on horror channel (UK) a few years ago?   A man was locked (and probably chained, but not sure about chain) by his own relative (most probably by his own mother) because he had in his gene/blood the proximity to sexual depravity – his ancestor had this characteristic (most probably incest, but not sure).  He at some stage had escaped from there and so on..

Comment: Can you clarify the Fantasy or Sci-Fi aspect of this? She's he transform? Magically lure girls?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I'm no biologist but I think the "deviant" gene would qualify to make it SFF? (granted, it's murky)

Comment: @jenayeh: Sounds more like Victorian pseudoscience of "bad blood".

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, it sounds kind of Steampunkish.